# Kivy countdown application

Tags: python, events, kivy, intervals, schedule

I have a problem that when I deleted `dt` argument in `count_down` function my application has been interrupted. I want to know what is `dt`?

I looked it up in the kivy documentation and saw `dt` arg in a different example, but I can't understand it! Maybe the duration? How does it work?

Here is my `__main__.py` source code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '400')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '280')


class RootWidget(GridLayout):
    counter = NumericProperty(25)
    condition = False

    def start(self):
        if not self.condition:
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.count_down, 1)
            self.condition = True
            return 'Start'
        else:
            return 'Already started'

    def pause(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.count_down, 1)
        self.condition = False
        return 'Pause'

    def stop(self):
        self.counter = 0
        return 'Stop'

    def count_down(self, dt):
        if self.counter > 0:
            self.counter -= 1
        else:
            self.stop()


class ClockApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__=="__main__":
    ClockApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

from the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html): `# dt means delta-time`.

Comment: When you schedule a call to some method using `Clock.schedule_once` or `Clock.schedule_interval`, the `dt` argument of the called method will provide the actual time delay till that method is called. For example, `Clock.schedule_interval(self.func, 0.5)` will schedule a call to `self.func` approximately every half second. When `self.func(self, dt)` actually gets called, `dt` will contain the actual time delay (something close to half a second).